# Pulling specific columns from a list of data frames using a function and lapply

Tags: r, list, function, lapply

I have a list of Data Frames named `StatesList` (it's a list of states), and I'm trying to pull out two Columns from each one, sum it, and return the sums. This is what I have so far:

```
StatesList <- list(Alabam, Alask, Arizon, Arkansa, Californi, Colorado, Connecticu, Delawar, District_ColUmbi, Florid, Georgi, Hawai, Idah, Illinoi, Indian, Iow, Kansa, Kentuck, Louisian, Main, Marylan, Massachusett, Michiga, Minnesot, Mississipp, Missour, Montan, Nebrask, Nevad, New_Hamp, New_Jer, New_Mex, New_York, North_Carol, North_Dak, Ohi, Oklahom, Orego, Pennsylvani, Rhode_Isl, South_Carol, South_Dak, Tennesse, Texa, Uta,Vermon, Virgini, Washingto, West_Vir, Wisconsi, Wyomin )

my_function <- function(x) {

  c <- sum(x + $Clinton_Weighted)
  t <- sum(x + $Trump_Weighted)
  ans <- list(Clinton = c, Trump = t)
  return(print(ans))
}

lapply(StatesList, my_function(x))
```

I know that `x + $Clinton_Weighted` won't work, but I'm not sure what will. 
How do I pull out that specific column in the function's code? And is trying to combine the names of each list with the `$` and the desired column a bad idea?

Comment: I think so, if a pairwise sum of all columns means the sum of two columns form each state printed out in a list.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that code. (I'm not super experienced with R) But what a desired output would be would look like is something like this:


    `[1] #for alabama

    Clinton  Trump

    87.5        78.4

    [2] #for alaska

    Clinton  Trump

    67.5        98.4`

.

.

.

all the way down the list of states.


Does that help?

Comment: `[1] #for alabama Clinton Trump 57.5, 48.4 [2] #for alaska Clinton Trump 27.5, 68.4 . . .`                    where the numbers are the sums of columns inside data frames inside of the list.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry about that. I'll try and figure out how to do that and get an example up here.

Comment: Are the two columns you consider for `sum` the same across all the States, if so, you could pass the column name to the function as, `my_function <- function(x="Alabama",colName1="alpha") { c <- sum(x[,colName1] + x[,"Clinton_Weighted"] ...) }`

Comment: And later `lapply(StatesList, my_function,"alpha")`

Comment: Ossan's solution should work.  But if Clinton_Weighted and Trump_Weighted are column names in every data frame in the list then  `c <- sum(x$Clinton_Weighted)
  t <- sum(x$Trump_Weighted)` should work as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do this using a combination of `lapply` and `apply`:

```
# Create sample data
cols = list(Clinton = 1:10, Trump = 10:1, SomeoneElse = 21:30)

Alabama = data.frame(cols)
Alaska = data.frame(cols)
Arison = data.frame(cols)
Arkansa = data.frame(cols)
Californi = data.frame(cols)

df_list = list(Alabama, Alaska, Arison, Arkansa, Californi)
```

The list of dataframes look like this:

```
df_list
[[1]]
   Clinton Trump SomeoneElse
1        1    10          21
2        2     9          22
3        3     8          23
4        4     7          24
5        5     6          25
6        6     5          26
7        7     4          27
8        8     3          28
9        9     2          29
10      10     1          30

[[2]]
   Clinton Trump SomeoneElse
1        1    10          21
2        2     9          22
3        3     8          23
4        4     7          24
5        5     6          25
6        6     5          26
7        7     4          27
8        8     3          28
9        9     2          29
10      10     1          30

[[3]]
   Clinton Trump SomeoneElse
1        1    10          21
2        2     9          22
3        3     8          23
4        4     7          24
5        5     6          25
6        6     5          26
7        7     4          27
8        8     3          28
9        9     2          29
10      10     1          30

[[4]]
   Clinton Trump SomeoneElse
1        1    10          21
2        2     9          22
3        3     8          23
4        4     7          24
5        5     6          25
6        6     5          26
7        7     4          27
8        8     3          28
9        9     2          29
10      10     1          30

[[5]]
   Clinton Trump SomeoneElse
1        1    10          21
2        2     9          22
3        3     8          23
4        4     7          24
5        5     6          25
6        6     5          26
7        7     4          27
8        8     3          28
9        9     2          29
10      10     1          30
```

Now sum up the columns of the dataframe, and apply it over the list of dataframes:

```
# Choose the columns to extract the sum of
cols = c("Clinton", "Trump")

lapply(df_list, function(x) apply(x[cols], 2, sum))
```

Below is the returned list

```
[[1]]
Clinton   Trump 
     55      55 

[[2]]
Clinton   Trump 
     55      55 

[[3]]
Clinton   Trump 
     55      55 

[[4]]
Clinton   Trump 
     55      55 

[[5]]
Clinton   Trump 
     55      55
```

Comment: @Travasaurus Is this the desired output?

Comment: What if I would like to get the sum of each data frame, but as a vectors with (10x1) with the sums of all rows of each data frame. I tried with rowSums, but it requires an array and I am stuck.